# 0 hashes per second in Qt for new altcoin

Tags: network, altcoin, education

Lately I have become interested in the way crytocurrency works. So I decided to make my own cryptocurrency to learn it's internal workings.

I used a clone of [SmallChange](https://github.com/bfroemel/smallchange) and followed [this](http://dogecoin.ga/how_to_create_scrypt_based_altcoins.html) guide.

Everything compiled well, but when I run the program, be it via command line or the qt interface, when I tell it to start mining it just tells me that it is mining but the hashespersecond are 0.

I tried building the litecoin source on my machine and used the exact same configuration that I used in my own altcoin (the same ".conf" file) and when I tell it to mine it does mine.
For my altcoin I used the ports:

> 55883 for RCP
>
> 55884 for P2P

My question is, is my computer not mining my altcoin because I'm alone on the network or it is happening because I have made some mistake in my code?

Thank you in advance :)

Edit: my output for "getinfo" is:

```
{
 "version" : 1000000,
 "protocolversion" : 60001,
 "walletversion" : 60000,
 "balance" : 0.00000000,
 "blocks" : 0,
 "connections" : 0,
 "proxy" : "",
 "difficulty" : 0.00024414,
 "testnet" : false,
 "keypoololdest" : 1369621665,
 "keypoolsize" : 101,
 "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
 "mininput" : 0.00010000,
 "errors" : ""
}
```

and the output for "getmininginfo" is:

```
 {
 "blocks" : 0,
 "currentblocksize" : 1000,
 "currentblocktx" : 0,
 "difficulty" : 0.00024414,
 "errors" : "",
 "generate" : true,
 "genproclimit" : 4,
 "hashespersec" : 0,
 "networkhashps" : -9223372036854775808,
 "pooledtx" : 0,
 "testnet" : false


}
```

Comment: Could you please post the output you are getting. It would help narrow down the list of what could have gone wrong :)

Comment: which output do you mean? the debug or the output for "getinfo" or "getmininginfo"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i did same thing bro :) i am very happy when you saw your question :) firstly you have to connect another computer . and you have to see "connection=1" To do that, you have use command: ./testcoin -connect= # . and you have to add listen=1 to main pc and addnode for both pcs.However, hashespersec is also zero for me :(

Comment: I got it to work.. Did you use "setgenerate" to tell it to start mining ??

Comment: ye i did, now, i have mining part. but i still can't see my coins in my wallet address :S do you know what the answer is for this ?

Comment: if you are mining with the wallet it means you are solo mining (and using a very bad mining software), so it's very difficult for you to earn coins.. your best choice for mining will be joining a mining pool

Comment: i did almost the same thing. however, my hashes per sec is 0 for mainnet. it works on testnet :S why :S

Comment: Hmm I was reading that on testnet all connections are permitted while on the mainet only the connections coming from the ip you specify are permitted .. Maybe you haven't specified the correct ip on the config file ... You can use 0.0.0.0 to permit all connections, however that's not a very smart idea.... Also, have you specified the 'server' and 'listen' values in your config file?

Comment: i did this. i set rpcallowip=0.0.0.0 and listen=1 and server=1 for server pc. other pc only have the rpcallowip=0.0.0.0 . however, the hashespersec did not change. do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: are you connecting the computers with the "connect" parameter? insted of 0.0.0.0 try rpcallowip=192.168.*.*
 if both pcs are on the same network. I hope you can get it to work